# Probability distribution satisfying constraints?

Tags: probability, distributions, density-function, beta-distribution

Reposted from Math.SE:

Continuing from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593512/what-is-a-function-satisfying-these-constraints). Given two random variables $X$ and $Y$ where $X \sim \operatorname{Beta}(a, b)$ and $Y \sim \operatorname{Beta}(c, d)$, I'm looking for a random variable $Z$ with a distribution supported on $[0, 1]$ that satisfies the following constraints:

1. The pdf of $Z$ has reflection symmetry: $f(x;a, b, c, d)=f(1-x;d, c, b, a)$
2. If $\mathrm{E}[X] > \frac{1}{2}$, then $\mathrm{E}[Z] > \mathrm{E}[Y]$
3. If $\mathrm{E}[X] = \frac{1}{2}$, then $\mathrm{E}[Z] = \mathrm{E}[Y]$
4. If $\mathrm{E}[X] < \frac{1}{2}$, then $\mathrm{E}[Z] < \mathrm{E}[Y]$
5. Increasing the expectation of $X$ or $Y$ must never decrease the expectation of $Z$.

Is an answer to this question even possible? The answer to my first question does not seem to solve the problem (the expectations are OK, but the support constraint is violated).

Comment: Please don't crosspost [questions from other SE sites](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/635453/probability-distribution-satisfying-constraints). As the [help explains](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): "*cross-posting is not encouraged on SE sites. Choose one best location to post your question. Later, if it proves better suited on another site, it can be migrated.*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beta distribution ${\rm Beta}\left(ac,bd\right)$ comes close, but it has the symmetries $f(x;a,b,c,d)=f(1−x;d,c,b,a)$ and $f(x;a,b,c,d)=f(x;c,d,a,b)$.

Comment: Aaactually, this will work. I just realized I made an error in my question. D'oh! (I really meant $f(x; a, b, c, d) = f(1- x; d, c, b, a)$). I will amend the question. Thanks!